# How can I kill a single shot QtCore.QTimer in PyQt4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer, pyqt, pyqt4

So, in my application, I create a single `QtCore.QTimer` object and then call the `singleShot` method on it to evoke a function after say 60 secs. Now, at any given point in time, if I would need to call the `singleShot` method on it again and prevent the previous `singleShot` method from taking effect (that is preventing it from calling the caller passed to it, if the second time the `singleShot` is invoked before the first 60 seconds), what do I need to do? How can I 'kill' the previous `QTimer` and completely forget about it and work only with the current `QTimer`?

Can someone help me out with this?

Here's just a sample code:

```
def main():
    q = QtCore.QTimer()
    q.singleShot(4000, print_hello)
    q.killTimer(id)     ##how can I get the value of 'id' so that print_hello() is not called before the end of the 4 seconds?

def print_hello():
    print 'hello'
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it necessary to create a second `QTimer` if there already exist one?

Comment: @BleedingFingers Thanks! Edited the description accordingly...can you please see if it makes better sense?

Comment: It's more obfuscated now, the earlier one was better. ;)

Comment: I think you don't need to instantiate the timer here: `q = QtCore.QTimer()` -> `q = QtCore.QTimer`. singleShot is static.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that `QTimer.singleShot()` does not return a reference to the `QTimer`. I don't know of anyway to get the Timer ID so you can kill it using that method. However, you can instantiate a normal `QTimer` and make it a single-shot timer (this is not what you have done in your code provided, calling `singleShot` on an instance of `QTimer` creates a **new** `QTimer` which you do not have access to.)

However, all is not lost. You can create a normal `QTimer` and convert it to a single shot timer using `setSingleShot(True)`. This allows you to call the `stop()` method if you wish to abort the timer. See the code example below which does what you require, on a 3 second timeout. You can push the button as many times as you like in rapid succession, and it will print "hello" once, 3 seconds after you stop. If you push it once, wait 4 seconds, and push it again, it will of course print out twice!

Hope that helps!

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.current_timer = None
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('start timer')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def start_timer(self):
        if self.current_timer:
            self.current_timer.stop()
            self.current_timer.deleteLater()
        self.current_timer = QTimer()
        self.current_timer.timeout.connect(self.print_hello)
        self.current_timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.current_timer.start(3000)

    def print_hello(self):
        print 'hello'


# Create QApplication and QWidget
qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)  
app = MyApp()
app.show()
qapp.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on [@three_pineapples's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21081371/1035647), and simplifying the code some.
There is no need to create a new `QTimer` on every button click, you only need to call `.start()` on the existing timer, and it will be stopped and started again.

See the [PyQt4 documentation for `QTimer.start()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtimer.html#start).

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
)

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.button = QPushButton('Start timer')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.hello)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)

    def start_timer(self):
        self.timer.start(3000)

    def hello(self):
        print('Hello!')

# Create QApplication and QWidget
qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)  
app = MyApp()
app.show()
qapp.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the creation of a second `QTimer` is entirely necessary then your approach is decent enough. What you could do it create a function or class that would such bookkeeping.

You could use the [`QBasicTimer`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qbasictimer.html). The doc:

> The QTimer class provides a high-level programming interface with single-shot timers and timer signals instead of events. There is also a QBasicTimer class that is more lightweight than QTimer and less clumsy than using timer IDs directly.

If you want to get rid of the `current_timer` entirely then I would suggest you call the [`current_timer.deleteLater`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#deleteLater) function. Make sure you assign a new `QTimer` to it as soon as you call this function or `del`/delete it by `del current_timer` or else if you reference any it's attributes later it will raise an error saying something like `C++ object not found`.

Comment: Thanks, though I am still not completely sure as to what to do! I guess I have to read up the docs for Qtimers better. Just to make matters simpler, if I have a singleShot QTimer that is scheduled to call a function say after T seconds, how can I stop it from doing so at some t < T?

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import (
QApplication,
QWidget,
QVBoxLayout,
QPushButton,)

class MyApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.button = QPushButton('Start timer')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)

        self.button1 = QPushButton('Stop timer')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.stop_timer)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.hello)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(False)


    def start_timer(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def stop_timer(self):       
        self.timer.stop ()
        print('timer stop')

    def hello(self):
        b=1   
        print(a)
        a.append(b)
        print(a)
        if len(a) == 5:
            self.timer.stop ()
            print('timer stop')


a=[]
# Create QApplication and QWidget
qapp = QApplication(sys.argv)  
app = MyApp()
app.show()
qapp.exec_()
```

Comment: not the best but you can get some idea how to stop qtimer

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Only-code answers are usually frowned upon.

Comment: use the method self.timer.stop () to kill your timer. it works both  self.timer.setSingleShot(True) and  self.timer.setSingleShot(False). in my example, i created a push button to stop the timer and a if statement as well.