# Stop a QTimer.singleShot() timer

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtimer

1. Is it possible to stop a `QTimer.singleShot()` timer? (Please don't tell 
   me to use the `stop()` function of a `QTimer` object - I really want to 
   know if the static function `QTimer.singleShot()` can be stopped before 
   its time has elapsed)
2. What happens if a second `QTimer.singleShot()` is launched before the 
   first one has elapsed? Is the first one killed, or is a second one 
   started instead?

Comment: You are [Geert Vancompernolle](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-February/022023.html) and I claim my €5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I kill a single shot QtCore.QTimer in PyQt4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21079941/how-can-i-kill-a-single-shot-qtcore-qtimer-in-pyqt4)

Comment: @three_pineapples. That doesn't definitively answer the question about stopping single-shot timers started using the static function.

Answer (score 3):

> Q. What happens if a second QTimer.singleShot() is launched before the
>   first one has elapsed? Is the first one killed or is a second one
>   started instead?

- All timers work independently, so if two are started in succession, both will run until completion.

> Q. Is it possible to stop a QTimer.singleShot() timer? (Please don't tell
>   me to use the stop() function of a QTimer object - I really want to
>   know if the static function QTimer.singleShot() can be stopped before
>   its time has elapsed)

- The static function creates an internal object that handles the timer, so there is no public API available to stop it. However, there is a hack involving `QAbstractEventDispatcher` which can work around this restriction. It relies on an implementation detail, so it is not recommended that this is used in production code. But you asked whether it was *possible*, so here is a demo:

  ```
  from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

  class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
      def __init__(self):
          super(Window, self).__init__()
          self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Start', self)
          self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleTimer)
          self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
          self.edit.setReadOnly(True)
          layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
          layout.addWidget(self.button)
          layout.addWidget(self.edit)
          self._timer = None

      def handleTimer(self):
          dispatcher = QtCore.QAbstractEventDispatcher.instance()
          if self._timer is None:
              self.edit.clear()
              self.button.setText('Stop')
              QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.handleTimeout)
              self._timer = dispatcher.children()[-1]
          else:
              dispatcher = QtCore.QAbstractEventDispatcher.instance()
              dispatcher.unregisterTimers(self._timer)
              self.button.setText('Start')
              self._timer = None

      def handleTimeout(self):
          self._timer = None
          self.button.setText('Start')
          self.edit.setText('timeout')

  if __name__ == '__main__':

      import sys
      app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
      window = Window()
      window.setGeometry(500, 150, 300, 100)
      window.show()
      sys.exit(app.exec_())
  ```